# We are not receiving push notification when large text send by user.

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, xmpp, ejabberd, erl

We are not receiving a push notification when large text sends by the user.
We are using below mod_apns.erl file.

mod_apns.erl - https://github.com/joanlopez/ejabberd-mod-apns/blob/master/src/mod_apns.erl
Ejabberd version - 16.09

How to truncate text message when send push notification using mod_apns.erl file?
I am new in erlang so, please help me.

Thanks